# Transparent image has a white background

Tags: css, sass, background-image, styled-components

I have a few png images that are supposed to have a transparent background, but when I add them into my component, it's given a white background for some weird reason: [image: bg images]

These are added as background images and I've been trying to make their background transparent:

```
const StyledImage = styled.div<ImageType>`
  height: 260px;
  width: 128px;
  background: transparent url(${({ mobileImage }) => mobileImage}) no-repeat;
  ${breakpoint('tabletMin')`
    background: transparent url(${({ image }) => image}) no-repeat;
    height: 585px;
    width: 288px;
  `};
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
`;
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I even tried to change this to `<img>` tags and adding a background image of transparent but it still doesn't work. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please create a snippet so we can inspect the code?

Comment: We need the **actual** images also. My guess is that these aren't in fact transparent images.